# What permission have to set for SQL user for configuration of change tracking in Database?

Tags: t-sql, permissions, change-tracking

I am building application which have to have option to configure (disable/enable) change tracking on tables on specific database. I am connecting to database via SQL user. Which database permissions need to add for SQL user for disable/enable change tracking on tables and option to run below query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       sct1.name                                             AS CT_schema
       , sot1.name                                           AS CT_table
       , ps1.row_count                                       AS CT_rows
       , sct2.name                                           AS tracked_schema
       , sot2.name                                           AS tracked_name
       , CHANGE_TRACKING_MIN_VALID_VERSION(sot2.object_id)   AS min_valid_version
       , itt.create_date                                     AS change_tracking_table_creation_date
       , CAST(ps1.reserved_page_count * 8. / 1024 AS BIGINT) AS CT_reserved_MB
       , CAST(ps2.reserved_page_count * 8. / 1024 AS BIGINT) AS tracked_base_table_MB
       , ps2.row_count                                       AS tracked_rows
FROM sys.internal_tables            it
JOIN sys.objects                    sot1
  ON it.object_id = sot1.object_id
JOIN sys.schemas                    AS sct1
  ON sot1.schema_id = sct1.schema_id
JOIN sys.dm_db_partition_stats      ps1
  ON it.object_id = ps1.object_id
     AND ps1.index_id IN (0, 1)
LEFT JOIN sys.objects               sot2
       ON it.parent_object_id = sot2.object_id
LEFT JOIN sys.schemas               AS sct2
       ON sot2.schema_id = sct2.schema_id
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_db_partition_stats ps2
       ON sot2.object_id = ps2.object_id
          AND ps2.index_id IN (0, 1)
INNER JOIN sys.internal_tables      itt
        ON itt.name = sot1.name
WHERE it.internal_type IN (209, 210);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach is a combination of trying and reading documentation.

I'm assuming the Change Tracking (CT) is already enabled on the Database level.

Let's create a new login and user in that Database (I'm using StackOverflow)

```sql
CREATE LOGIN BillyNoRights WITH PASSWORD = '$tr0ngPassword'
GO
USE [StackOverflow]
GO 
CREATE USER BillyNoRights FROM LOGIN BillyNoRights
```

Then you can impersonate the Login and run your query.

```sql
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'BillyNoRights'
SELECT DISTINCT
       sct1.name  
…
```

Giving you an error:

> Msg 262, Level 14, State 1, Line 9
> VIEW DATABASE STATE permission
> denied in database 'StackOverflow'.
> Msg 297, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
> The user does not have permission to perform this action.

(This applies to SQL 2019 and earlier. The permissions for SQL 2022 is `VIEW DATABASE PERFORMANCE STATE`)

If you grant this permission (from a different session that's not impersonating), you can run your query.

```sql
GRANT VIEW DATABASE STATE TO BillyNoRights
```

The second part is about enabling Change Tracking on any table. You didn't provide a code for this, but the syntax is simple

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.Votes
ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING
```

This time, the error isn't so useful

> Msg 1088, Level 16, State 13, Line 40
> Cannot find the object "Votes" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

We have to look at the [documentation for the Alter Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#permissions) statement

> Requires ALTER permission on the table.

We can grant granular permission on tables, but since you want to be able to enable CT on any table (possibly even future tables), we have to get less granular.

The closest Database-level permission I could find is

```sql
GRANT ALTER ANY SCHEMA TO BillyNoRights
```

which works, but it gives the user permission to `ALTER` any objects (procedures, functions, etc.)

So I would recommend a dynamic SQL wrapped in a stored procedure with a table name as a parameter.

How to do this correctly and without SQL injections is outside of the scope of this question, so I would point you to [Packaging Permissions in Stored Procedures by Erland Sommarskog](https://sommarskog.se/grantperm.html)